# 同じ設定で、動きが違う理由は？

Tags: javascript

下記の３つのソースコードは、アナログ時計(マウスストーカー)のサイズを変えるために
pulldown式のボタンを用いたものです。

1つ目のソースは、掟破りでoptionタグ内にonClickを使ってイベントを発生させたものですが、
動きそのものはスムーズで問題はありません。

しかし2つ目のソースは、本道selectタグ内にonChangeを用いたものですが、動きがギクシャクしていて同じスクリプトの内容とは思えません。どうすれば、1つ目のソースのようにスムーズに動くようになるでしょうか。

３つめのソースは、サイズは切り替わるのですが、記述が足りないためか"秒針"･"分針"･"時間針"のサイズはそのままの大きさで変化しません。問題箇所を指摘していただたら、幸いです。

1つ目のソースです。

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=shift_jis"> 

<TITLE>妖怪クロック(アナログ) - JavaScript</TITLE>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
.butt{
BACKGROUND:maroon; 
COLOR:gold;
}
//-->
</style>
</head>

<BODY bgcolor="black" text="white">

<div id="clock" style="visibility:hidden">
    <div id="Od" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Of" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Oh" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Om" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Os" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

// 状態変数>
var scale = 1;
var transitionStarted = 0;
var transitionFrom = 0;
var transitionTo = 0;
var transitionDuration = 0;

// サイズの変更を開始する処理

function changeSIZE1()
{
    transitionStarted = new Date().getTime();
    transitionFrom = scale;
    transitionTo =  2.5; // 最終的な倍率。状態により変化
    transitionDuration = 1000;
}
function changeSIZE2()
{
    transitionStarted = new Date().getTime();
    transitionFrom = scale;
    transitionTo =  1; // 最終的な倍率。状態により変化
    transitionDuration = 1000;
}
function changeSIZE3()
{
    transitionStarted = new Date().getTime();
    transitionFrom = scale;
    transitionTo = 0.5; // 最終的な倍率。状態により変化
    transitionDuration = 1000;
}



(function(){
    "use strict";

function $(sel)
{
    return document.getElementById(sel);
}

function $$(sel)
{
    if (typeof document.getElementsByClassName === 'undefined')
    {
        return document.getElementsByName(sel);
    }
    return document.getElementsByClassName(sel);
}

var dCol = '', //date colour.
    sCol = '', //seconds colour.
    mCol = '', //minutes colour.
    hCol = '', //hours colour.
    fCol = '', //face color

    ClockHeight = 65,
    ClockWidth = 65,
    ClockFromMouseY = 0,
    ClockFromMouseX = 100,
    d = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
    m = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
    date = new Date(),
    day = date.getDate(),
    year = date.getYear() + 1900;
var TodaysDate = " " + d[date.getDay()] + " " + day + " " + m[date.getMonth()] + " " + year;
var D = TodaysDate.split('');
var H = '☆☆☆';
    H = H.split('');
var M = '☆☆☆☆';
    M = M.split('');
var S = '・・・・・';
    S = S.split('');
var Face = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12',
    font = 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
    size = 1,
    speed = 0.55;
    Face = Face.split(' ');
var n = Face.length;
var a = size * 10;
var ymouse = 0,
    xmouse = 0,
    scrll = 0,
    props = '<span style="font-family:' + font + ';font-size:' + size + 'em; color:#' + fCol + '">',
    props2 = '<span style="font-family:' + font + ';font-size:' + size + 'em; color:#' + dCol + '">';
var Split = 360 / n;
var Dsplit = 360 / D.length;
var HandHeight = ClockHeight / 4.5; 
var HandWidth = ClockWidth / 4.5;
var HandY = -7,
    HandX = -2.5,
    step = 0.02,
    currStep = 0,
    y = [],
    x = [],
    Y = [],
    X = [],
    Dy = [],
    Dx = [],
    DY = [],
    DX = [];
var i;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    y[i] = 0;
    x[i] = 0;
    Y[i] = 0;
    X[i] = 0;
}

for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++) 
{
    Dy[i] = 0;
    Dx[i] = 0;
    DY[i] = 0;
    DX[i] = 0;
}
var wrapper = $('clock');
var html = '';
// Date wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Date" name="Date" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0;height:' + a + ';width:' + a + ';text-align:center">' + props2 + D[i] + '</span></div>';
}
$('Od').children[0].innerHTML = html;

// Face wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    html += '<div class="Face" name="Face" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0;height:' + a + ';width:' + a + ';text-align:center">' + props + Face[i] + '</span></div>';
}
$('Of').children[0].innerHTML = html;
// Hours wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < H.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Hours" name="Hours" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + hCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + H[i] + '</div>';
} 
$('Oh').children[0].innerHTML = html;
// Minute wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < M.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Minutes" name="Minutes" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + mCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + M[i] + '</div>';
} 
$('Om').children[0].innerHTML = html;
// Seconds wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < S.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Seconds" name="Seconds" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + sCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + S[i] + '</div>';
} 
$('Os').children[0].innerHTML = html;
// Mouse move event handler

function Mouse(evnt) 
{
    if (typeof evnt === 'undefined')
    {
        ymouse = event.Y + ClockFromMouseY;
        xmouse = event.X + ClockFromMouseX;
    }
    else
    {
        ymouse = evnt.clientY + ClockFromMouseY;
        xmouse = evnt.clientX + ClockFromMouseX;
    }
}

document.onmousemove = Mouse;

function ClockAndAssign() 
{
    var time = new Date();

    // 状態変更処理
    if(transitionStarted)
    {
        var d = time.getTime() - transitionStarted;
        if (d < transitionDuration)
        {
            scale = transitionFrom + (transitionTo - transitionFrom) * d / transitionDuration;
        }
        else
        {
            // トランジション終了
            scale = transitionTo;
            transitionStarted = 0;
        }
    }

    var secs = time.getSeconds();
    var sec = -1.57 + Math.PI * secs / 30;
    var mins = time.getMinutes();
    var min = -1.57 + Math.PI * mins / 30;
    var hr = time.getHours();
    var hrs = -1.575 + Math.PI * hr / 6 + Math.PI * parseInt(time.getMinutes(), 10) / 360;
    $('Od').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Of').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Oh').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Om').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Os').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        var F = $$('Face')[i];
        F.style.top = y[i] + scale * ClockHeight * Math.sin(-1.0471 + i * Split * Math.PI / 180) + scrll;
        F.style.left = x[i] + scale * ClockWidth * Math.cos(-1.0471 + i * Split * Math.PI / 180);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < H.length; i++)
    {
        var HL = $$('Hours')[i];
        HL.style.top = y[i] + HandY + scale * (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(hrs) + scrll;
        HL.style.left = x[i] + HandX + scale * (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(hrs);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < M.length; i++)
    {
        var ML = $$('Minutes')[i].style;
        ML.top = y[i] + HandY + scale * (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(min) + scrll;
        ML.left = x[i] + HandX + scale * (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(min);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < S.length; i++)
    {
        var SL = $$('Seconds')[i].style;
        SL.top = y[i] + HandY + scale * (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(sec) + scrll;
        SL.left = x[i] + HandX + scale * (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(sec);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++)
    {
        var DL = $$('Date')[i].style;
        DL.top = Dy[i] + scale * ClockHeight * 1.5 * Math.sin(currStep + i * Dsplit * Math.PI / 180) + scrll;
        DL.left = Dx[i] + scale * ClockWidth * 1.5 * Math.cos(currStep + i * Dsplit * Math.PI / 180);
    }
    currStep -= step;
}

function Delay() 
{
    scrll = 0;
    Dy[0] = Math.round(DY[0] += ((ymouse) - DY[0]) * speed);
    Dx[0] = Math.round(DX[0] += ((xmouse) - DX[0]) * speed);

    for (i = 1; i < D.length; i++) {
        Dy[i] = Math.round(DY[i] += (Dy[i - 1] - DY[i]) * speed);
        Dx[i] = Math.round(DX[i] += (Dx[i - 1] - DX[i]) * speed);
    }
    y[0] = Math.round(Y[0] += ((ymouse) - Y[0]) * speed);
    x[0] = Math.round(X[0] += ((xmouse) - X[0]) * speed);

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        y[i] = Math.round(Y[i] += (y[i - 1] - Y[i]) * speed);
        x[i] = Math.round(X[i] += (x[i - 1] - X[i]) * speed);
    }
    ClockAndAssign();
    setTimeout(Delay, 20);
}

Delay();

}());

num = 1;
function toggle(){
 num ^= 1; 
if(num == 1){
    document.getElementById('clock').style.visibility="hidden";
    document.getElementById('size').disabled=true;
} 
else {
    document.getElementById('clock').style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById('size').disabled=false;
}
document.getElementById("tog").value = num ?" APPEAR ":"KILL(切る)";
}
//-->
</script>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div align="center"><div>
<input class="butt" type="button" id="tog" value="今何時？" onclick="toggle()">
</div><br>
<div>
<select id="size" style="background:lightblue" disabled>
<option onClick="changeSIZE1()">２.５倍</option>
<option onClick="changeSIZE2()" selected>サイズ</option>
<option onClick="changeSIZE3()">半　 分</option>
</select>
</div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

2つ目のソースです。
記述コード以上は、同じですので省略します。

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// 状態変数>
var scale = 1;
var transitionStarted = 0;
var transitionFrom = 0;
var transitionTo = 0;
var transitionDuration = 0;

// サイズの変更を開始する処理

function changeSIZE(value)
{
    transitionStarted = new Date().getTime();
    transitionFrom = scale;
    transitionTo =  value; // 最終的な倍率。状態により変化
    transitionDuration = 1000;
}

(function(){
    "use strict";

function $(sel)
{
    return document.getElementById(sel);
}

function $$(sel)
{
    if (typeof document.getElementsByClassName === 'undefined')
    {
        return document.getElementsByName(sel);
    }
    return document.getElementsByClassName(sel);
}

var dCol = '', //date colour.
    sCol = '', //seconds colour.
    mCol = '', //minutes colour.
    hCol = '', //hours colour.
    fCol = '', //face color

    ClockHeight = 65,
    ClockWidth = 65,
    ClockFromMouseY = 0,
    ClockFromMouseX = 100,
    d = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
    m = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
    date = new Date(),
    day = date.getDate(),
    year = date.getYear() + 1900;
var TodaysDate = " " + d[date.getDay()] + " " + day + " " + m[date.getMonth()] + " " + year;
var D = TodaysDate.split('');
var H = '☆☆☆';
    H = H.split('');
var M = '☆☆☆☆';
    M = M.split('');
var S = '・・・・・';
    S = S.split('');
var Face = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12',
    font = 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
    size = 1,
    speed = 0.55;
    Face = Face.split(' ');
var n = Face.length;
var a = size * 10;
var ymouse = 0,
    xmouse = 0,
    scrll = 0,
    props = '<span style="font-family:' + font + ';font-size:' + size + 'em; color:#' + fCol + '">',
    props2 = '<span style="font-family:' + font + ';font-size:' + size + 'em; color:#' + dCol + '">';
var Split = 360 / n;
var Dsplit = 360 / D.length;
var HandHeight = ClockHeight / 4.5; 
var HandWidth = ClockWidth / 4.5;
var HandY = -7,
    HandX = -2.5,
    step = 0.02,
    currStep = 0,
    y = [],
    x = [],
    Y = [],
    X = [],
    Dy = [],
    Dx = [],
    DY = [],
    DX = [];
var i;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    y[i] = 0;
    x[i] = 0;
    Y[i] = 0;
    X[i] = 0;
}

for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++) 
{
    Dy[i] = 0;
    Dx[i] = 0;
    DY[i] = 0;
    DX[i] = 0;
}
var wrapper = $('clock');
var html = '';
// Date wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Date" name="Date" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0;height:' + a + ';width:' + a + ';text-align:center">' + props2 + D[i] + '</span></div>';
}
$('Od').children[0].innerHTML = html;

// Face wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    html += '<div class="Face" name="Face" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0;height:' + a + ';width:' + a + ';text-align:center">' + props + Face[i] + '</span></div>';
}
$('Of').children[0].innerHTML = html;
// Hours wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < H.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Hours" name="Hours" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + hCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + H[i] + '</div>';
} 
$('Oh').children[0].innerHTML = html;
// Minute wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < M.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Minutes" name="Minutes" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + mCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + M[i] + '</div>';
} 
$('Om').children[0].innerHTML = html;
// Seconds wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < S.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Seconds" name="Seconds" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + sCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + S[i] + '</div>';
} 
$('Os').children[0].innerHTML = html;
// Mouse move event handler

function Mouse(evnt) 
{
    if (typeof evnt === 'undefined')
    {
        ymouse = event.Y + ClockFromMouseY;
        xmouse = event.X + ClockFromMouseX;
    }
    else
    {
        ymouse = evnt.clientY + ClockFromMouseY;
        xmouse = evnt.clientX + ClockFromMouseX;
    }
}

document.onmousemove = Mouse;

function ClockAndAssign() 
{
    var time = new Date();

    // 状態変更処理
    if(transitionStarted)
    {
        var d = time.getTime() - transitionStarted;
        if (d < transitionDuration)
        {
            scale = transitionFrom + (transitionTo - transitionFrom) * d / transitionDuration;
        }
        else
        {
            // トランジション終了
            scale = transitionTo;
            transitionStarted = 0;
        }
    }

    var secs = time.getSeconds();
    var sec = -1.57 + Math.PI * secs / 30;
    var mins = time.getMinutes();
    var min = -1.57 + Math.PI * mins / 30;
    var hr = time.getHours();
    var hrs = -1.575 + Math.PI * hr / 6 + Math.PI * parseInt(time.getMinutes(), 10) / 360;
    $('Od').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Of').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Oh').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Om').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Os').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        var F = $$('Face')[i];
        F.style.top = y[i] + scale * ClockHeight * Math.sin(-1.0471 + i * Split * Math.PI / 180) + scrll;
        F.style.left = x[i] + scale * ClockWidth * Math.cos(-1.0471 + i * Split * Math.PI / 180);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < H.length; i++)
    {
        var HL = $$('Hours')[i];
        HL.style.top = y[i] + HandY + scale * (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(hrs) + scrll;
        HL.style.left = x[i] + HandX + scale * (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(hrs);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < M.length; i++)
    {
        var ML = $$('Minutes')[i].style;
        ML.top = y[i] + HandY + scale * (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(min) + scrll;
        ML.left = x[i] + HandX + scale * (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(min);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < S.length; i++)
    {
        var SL = $$('Seconds')[i].style;
        SL.top = y[i] + HandY + scale * (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(sec) + scrll;
        SL.left = x[i] + HandX + scale * (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(sec);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++)
    {
        var DL = $$('Date')[i].style;
        DL.top = Dy[i] + scale * ClockHeight * 1.5 * Math.sin(currStep + i * Dsplit * Math.PI / 180) + scrll;
        DL.left = Dx[i] + scale * ClockWidth * 1.5 * Math.cos(currStep + i * Dsplit * Math.PI / 180);
    }
    currStep -= step;
}

function Delay() 
{
    scrll = 0;
    Dy[0] = Math.round(DY[0] += ((ymouse) - DY[0]) * speed);
    Dx[0] = Math.round(DX[0] += ((xmouse) - DX[0]) * speed);

    for (i = 1; i < D.length; i++) {
        Dy[i] = Math.round(DY[i] += (Dy[i - 1] - DY[i]) * speed);
        Dx[i] = Math.round(DX[i] += (Dx[i - 1] - DX[i]) * speed);
    }
    y[0] = Math.round(Y[0] += ((ymouse) - Y[0]) * speed);
    x[0] = Math.round(X[0] += ((xmouse) - X[0]) * speed);

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        y[i] = Math.round(Y[i] += (y[i - 1] - Y[i]) * speed);
        x[i] = Math.round(X[i] += (x[i - 1] - X[i]) * speed);
    }
    ClockAndAssign();
    setTimeout(Delay, 20);
}

Delay();

}());

num = 1;
function toggle(){
 num ^= 1; 
if(num == 1){
    document.getElementById('clock').style.visibility="hidden";
    document.getElementById('size').disabled=true;
} 
else {
    document.getElementById('clock').style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById('size').disabled=false;
}
document.getElementById("tog").value = num ?" APPEAR ":"KILL(切る)";
}
//-->
</script>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div align="center"><div>
<input class="butt" type="button" id="tog" value="今何時？" onclick="toggle()">
</div><br>
<div>
<select id="size" style="background:lightblue" onChange="changeSIZE(this.value)" disabled>
<option value="2.5">２.５倍</option>
<option value="1" selected>サイズ</option>
<option value="0.5">半　 分</option>
</select>
</div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

３つ目のソースです。
記述コード以上は、同じですので省略します。

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

var ClockHeight = 55,
    ClockWidth = 55;

function changeSIZE(value){
    ClockHeight = value;
    ClockWidth = value;
}

(function(){
    "use strict";

function $(sel)
{
    return document.getElementById(sel);
}

function $$(sel)
{
    if (typeof document.getElementsByClassName === 'undefined')
    {
        return document.getElementsByName(sel);
    }
    return document.getElementsByClassName(sel);
}

var dCol = '', //date colour.
    sCol = '', //seconds colour.
    mCol = '', //minutes colour.
    hCol = '', //hours colour.
    fCol = '', //face color.


        ClockFromMouseY = 0,
    ClockFromMouseX = 100,
    d = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
    m = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
    date = new Date(),
    day = date.getDate(),
    year = date.getYear() + 1900;
var TodaysDate = " " + d[date.getDay()] + " " + day + " " + m[date.getMonth()] + " " + year;
var D = TodaysDate.split('');
var H = '☆☆☆';
    H = H.split('');
var M = '☆☆☆☆';
    M = M.split('');
var S = '・・・・・';
    S = S.split('');
var Face = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12',
    font = 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
    size = 1,
    speed = 0.55;
    Face = Face.split(' ');
var n = Face.length;
var a = size * 10;
var ymouse = 0,
    xmouse = 0,
    scrll = 0,
    props = '<span style="font-family:' + font + ';font-size:' + size + 'em; color:#' + fCol + '">',
    props2 = '<span style="font-family:' + font + ';font-size:' + size + 'em; color:#' + dCol + '">';
var Split = 360 / n;
var Dsplit = 360 / D.length;
var HandHeight = ClockHeight / 4.5; 
var HandWidth = ClockWidth / 4.5;
var     HandY = -7, 
    HandX = -2.5,   
        step = 0.02,
        currStep = 0,
    y = [],
    x = [],
    Y = [],
    X = [],
    Dy = [],
    Dx = [],
    DY = [],
    DX = [];
var i;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    y[i] = 0;
    x[i] = 0;
    Y[i] = 0;
    X[i] = 0;
}

for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++) 
{
    Dy[i] = 0;
    Dx[i] = 0;
    DY[i] = 0;
    DX[i] = 0;
}
var wrapper = $('clock');
var html = '';
// Date wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Date" name="Date" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0;height:' + a + ';width:' + a + ';text-align:center">' + props2 + D[i] + '</span></div>';
}
$('Od').children[0].innerHTML = html;

// Face wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    html += '<div class="Face" name="Face" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0;height:' + a + ';width:' + a + ';text-align:center">' + props + Face[i] + '</span></div>';
}
$('Of').children[0].innerHTML = html;
// Hours wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < H.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Hours" name="Hours" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + hCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + H[i] + '</div>';
} 
$('Oh').children[0].innerHTML = html;
// Minute wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < M.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Minutes" name="Minutes" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + mCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + M[i] + '</div>';
} 
$('Om').children[0].innerHTML = html;
// Seconds wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < S.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Seconds" name="Seconds" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + sCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + S[i] + '</div>';
} 
$('Os').children[0].innerHTML = html;
// Mouse move event handler

function Mouse(evnt) 
{
    if (typeof evnt === 'undefined')
    {
        ymouse = event.Y + ClockFromMouseY;
        xmouse = event.X + ClockFromMouseX;
    }
    else
    {
        ymouse = evnt.clientY + ClockFromMouseY;
        xmouse = evnt.clientX + ClockFromMouseX;
    }
}

document.onmousemove = Mouse;

function ClockAndAssign() 
{
    var time = new Date();
    var secs = time.getSeconds();
    var sec = -1.57 + Math.PI * secs / 30;
    var mins = time.getMinutes();
    var min = -1.57 + Math.PI * mins / 30;
    var hr = time.getHours();
    var hrs = -1.575 + Math.PI * hr / 6 + Math.PI * parseInt(time.getMinutes(), 10) / 360;
    $('Od').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Of').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Oh').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Om').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Os').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        var F = $$('Face')[i];
        F.style.top = y[i] + ClockHeight * Math.sin(-1.0471 + i * Split * Math.PI / 180) + scrll;
        F.style.left = x[i] + ClockWidth * Math.cos(-1.0471 + i * Split * Math.PI / 180);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < H.length; i++)
    {
        var HL = $$('Hours')[i];
        HL.style.top = y[i] + HandY + (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(hrs) + scrll;
        HL.style.left = x[i] + HandX + (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(hrs);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < M.length; i++)
    {
        var ML = $$('Minutes')[i].style;
        ML.top = y[i] + HandY + (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(min) + scrll;
        ML.left = x[i] + HandX + (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(min);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < S.length; i++)
    {
        var SL = $$('Seconds')[i].style;
        SL.top = y[i] + HandY + (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(sec) + scrll;
        SL.left = x[i] + HandX + (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(sec);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++)
    {
        var DL = $$('Date')[i].style;
        DL.top = Dy[i] + ClockHeight * 1.5 * Math.sin(currStep + i * Dsplit * Math.PI / 180) + scrll;
        DL.left = Dx[i] + ClockWidth * 1.5 * Math.cos(currStep + i * Dsplit * Math.PI / 180);
    }
    currStep -= step;
}

function Delay() 
{
    scrll = 0;
    Dy[0] = Math.round(DY[0] += ((ymouse) - DY[0]) * speed);
    Dx[0] = Math.round(DX[0] += ((xmouse) - DX[0]) * speed);

    for (i = 1; i < D.length; i++) {
        Dy[i] = Math.round(DY[i] += (Dy[i - 1] - DY[i]) * speed);
        Dx[i] = Math.round(DX[i] += (Dx[i - 1] - DX[i]) * speed);
    }
    y[0] = Math.round(Y[0] += ((ymouse) - Y[0]) * speed);
    x[0] = Math.round(X[0] += ((xmouse) - X[0]) * speed);

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        y[i] = Math.round(Y[i] += (y[i - 1] - Y[i]) * speed);
        x[i] = Math.round(X[i] += (x[i - 1] - X[i]) * speed);
    }
    ClockAndAssign();
    setTimeout(Delay, 20);
}

Delay();

}());

num = 1;
function toggle(){
 num ^= 1; 
 if(num == 1){ 
document.getElementById('clock').style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById('size').disabled=true;
 }
else { 
document.getElementById('clock').style.visibility="visible";
document.getElementById('size').disabled=false;
} 
document.getElementById("tog").value = num ?" Appear ":"Kill(切る)";
}
</script>


<font id="text1" size="5"><b>妖怪クロック(アナログ１)：</b></font>

<br><br><br>


<div align="center"><div>
<input class="butt" type="button" id="tog" value="今何時？" onclick="toggle()">
</div><br>
<div>
<select id="size" style="background:lightblue" onchange="changeSIZE(this.value)" disabled>
  <option value="138";"138">2.5倍</option>
  <option value="55";"55" selected>サイズ</option>
  <option value="28";"28">半　分</option>
</select>
</div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: あんまり違いは分からなかったのですが、ソース２で大きさがおかしくなることがありました。違いが`transitionTo` だけのことだとすると、`onChange="changeSIZE(1*this.value)"`を試してみたらどうでしょうか？、ソース３は見てません。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。
うまく動作しました。
ソース２は、"transitionDuration"の効果がないのでおかしいと思っていたのですが、そんな所に"1*"を付けるだけでよかったのですね。どんな意味があるのでしょうか。

Comment: `1*` については前回の質問で説明しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まず、1 と 2 の違いを抜き出してみます。

```
function changeSIZE1()
{
  transitionStarted = new Date().getTime();
  transitionFrom = scale;
  transitionTo =  2.5; // 最終的な倍率。状態により変化
  transitionDuration = 1000;
}

function changeSIZE(value)
{
  transitionStarted = new Date().getTime();
  transitionFrom = scale;
  transitionTo = value;
  transitionDuration = 1000;
}
```

異なるのは value だけです。では value には何が入るでしょうか？

```
<select id="size" style="background:lightblue" onChange="changeSIZE(this.value)" disabled>
  <option value="2.5">２.５倍</option>
  <option value="1" selected>サイズ</option>
  <option value="0.5">半　 分</option>
</select>
<select i
```

このとき、`this.value` に何が入るかというと、`"2.5"` です。
数値の`2.5` ではなく、文字列の`"2.5"`です。

よって、解法としては、下記のように数値に変換することで対応できると考えます

```
function changeSIZE(value)
{
  transitionStarted = new Date().getTime();
  transitionFrom = scale;
  transitionTo =  parseFloat(value); // 最終的な倍率。状態により変化
  transitionDuration = 1000;
}
```

Comment: ”１”をかけることで数値に置き換えるということでしたね。
ここでは"１*"でも"parseFloat(value) "でも、どちらかを使えば
数値に置き換えられるということですね。
ところで、１の場合は、個々にtransitionDurationの数値を
変えられますが、２の場合は、transitionDurationの数値を
変えることはできるのでしょうか。